# Assignment by reference confusion

Tags: javascript

I have a 'trades' object that includes a reference to orderBook.BTCUSDT. My intention is to change 'trades' when orderBook.BTCUSDT is changed.

However, changing orderBook.BTCUSDT does not work. But changing orderBook.BTCUSDT.asks does.

Why?

```js
orderBook = {'BTCUSDT': {'asks':[1,2,3,5], 'bids':[6,7,8,9]}};
trades = {"one": orderBook.BTCUSDT};
orderBook.BTCUSDT = 1234; // does not work
console.log(trades);

/* Output:
{
  "one": {
    "asks": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      5
    ],
    "bids": [
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9
    ]
  }
}
*/

orderBook = {'BTCUSDT': {'asks':[1,2,3,5], 'bids':[6,7,8,9]}};
trades = {"one": orderBook.BTCUSDT};
orderBook.BTCUSDT.asks = 1234; // works
console.log(trades);

/* Output:
{
  "one": {
    "asks": 1234,
    "bids": [
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9
    ]
  }
}
*/
```

**Edit after Axiac and Artur responses**

After reading responses from Axiac and Artur, I found another way to ask the question. Why does the first code block work but not the second? Why should I have to add another level to the object by using 'prices'? Seems like both are trying to do the same thing (replace an object with another object but keep the reference), just at different levels.

```js
orderBook = {BTCUSDT: { prices: {'asks':[1,2,3,5], 'bids':[6,7,8,9]}}};
trades = {one: orderBook.BTCUSDT};
orderBook.BTCUSDT.prices = {'asks':[11,12,13,15], 'bids':[16,17,18,19]};  // trades.one.BTCUSDT.prices is updated as expected 
console.log(trades); 

orderBook = {BTCUSDT: {'asks':[1,2,3,5], 'bids':[6,7,8,9]}};
trades = {one: orderBook.BTCUSDT};
orderBook.BTCUSDT = {'asks':[11,12,13,15], 'bids':[16,17,18,19]};  // trades.one.BTCUSDT is NOT updated as expected 
console.log(trades);
```

**EDIT: Mutation vs Reassignment**

I believe I found the answer inside [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference).

In both code blocks above, trades.one is set to orderBook.BTCUSDT.

In the second code block, orderBook.BTCUSDT is being *reassigned* with the third line whereas in the first code block orderBook.BTCUSDT is being *mutated* in the third line. Changing orderBook.BTCUSDT.prices is a mutation so the reference is not lost. However, with the second code block, the reassignment breaks the reference.

This is what axiac and Artur were also saying without explicitly discussing mutation VS reassignment.

Comment: You are assigning a value which is `Number` not an `Object`. Numbers are not mutable but Objects are hence assigned value does not reflect after updating Value from Object. If Object is assigned, after changing value, it would update.

Comment: @Rayon In this case he is changing the pointer not the object referenced ... so even if he changed the pointer with an `Object` (as you said) it would still have no impact on the other object which was referenced by the `trades`, please check my answer, for better visualisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement:

```
trades = {"one": orderBook.BTCUSDT};
```

makes `trades.one` refer to the same object as `orderBook.BTCUSDT` do (an object having the properties `asks` and `bids`). This way, the object can be accessed using two variables (`trades.one` and `orderBook.BTCUSDT`).

`trades.one` and `orderBook.BTCUSDT` are different entities and they are not related in any way. It just happens that after the statement above they point to the same object.

The next statement:

```
orderBook.BTCUSDT = 1234; // does not work
```

puts a different value in `orderBook.BTCUSDT` and breaks the link between it and the object. The object having the `asks` and `bids` properties can now be accessed only by using the `trades.one` variable.

Comment: axiac, please see my edit, which asks the question in a slightly different manner now.

Answer (score 5):

```
orderBook = {'BTCUSDT': {'asks':[1,2,3,5], 'bids':[6,7,8,9]}};
trades = {"one": orderBook.BTCUSDT};
```

**1. orderBook.BTCUSDT = 1234;**

[image]

[image]

**2.orderBook.BTCUSDT.asks = 1234;**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Artur, please see my edit, which asks the question in a slightly different manner now. What software do you use to create these visualizations?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will help you to understand visually why you have this behavior.

[image]
In the first picture you can see how the objects are referenced.

[image]
In the second picture you can see that by doing this   `orderBook.BTCUSDT = 1234` you cut the connection of `BTCUSDT` and the object it was pointing 
 before, so it does not point anymore, but the `trades` is still referencing that object.